# detect no disk space iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone

Suppose I need to write many images to iPhone file system. And I need to find I have enough space to write image to disk. Is it possible using iPhone SDK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. See the following tutorial (found using the powerful "google" search engine) ;)

http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/device-information/how-to-obtain-total-and-available-disk-space-on-your-iphone-or-ipod-touch

Edit: added response re: writing UIImage to disk, with unknown available disk space:

Try-Catch a bad way of doing things. Exceptions in cocoa are only for truly exceptionally circumstances (i.e. crash-worthy). If you write your image using

```
NSData *imageData = [myImage UIImageJPEGRepresentation];
```

(or UIImagePNGRepresentation)

and then

```
NSError *error;
BOOL success = [imageData writeToFile:(NSString *)path options:(NSDataWritingOptions)mask error:&error];
```

Your `BOOL` `failed` will tell you if it worked, and `error` will contain an `NSError` object with a description of the error (don't test for `error != nil` though, that'll crash occasionally).

Comment: You should initialize `NSError *error = nil;`, so you can safely test for `error != nil` after the call. :-) And then it won't crash anymore.

Comment: Straight from a WWDC talk: error values are *undefined* unless the method returns false. You should only ever check/trust/use the error value if the method returns false.

Comment: @KennyWinker Have you succeeded in inspecting this error? What message does the error contain when in not enough disk space condition?